# sklearn_crfsuite ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, cython

I have installed the sklearn-crfsuite using pip install sklearn-crfsuite on windows 10. My python is v 3.5.
I have the following error when want to import sklearn_crfsuite:

```
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File 
    "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
    packages\sklearn_crfsuite\__init__.py", line 2, in <module> from 
    .estimator import CRF File 
    "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
    packages\sklearn_crfsuite\estimator.py", line 6, in <module> import 
    pycrfsuite File 
    "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
    packages\pycrfsuite\__init__.py", line 2, in <module> from ._pycrfsuite 
    import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be 
    found.
```

I have the files msvcp_win.dll, msvcp60.dll, and msvcp100.dll in my Windows/System32.
what is the problem?

Comment: You used pip or pip3?

Comment: I used the pip. My default python is python 3. and I checked the site-package folder of my python 3. The library is installed correctly.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Atena You need to install visual c++. This will fix the DLL path problems, It did for me.